# How to install xgboost in Anaconda Python (Windows platform)?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, xgboost

I am a new Python user. I downloaded the latest Anaconda 3 2.4.1 (Python 3.5) from the below link:
https://www.continuum.io/downloads

My PC Configurations are: Windows 10, 64 bit, 4GB RAM

I have spent hours trying to find the right way to download the package after the 'pip install xgboost' failed in the Anaconda command prompt but couldn't find any specific instructions for Anaconda.

Can anyone help on how to install xgboost from Anaconda?

Comment: Though comment is late, use the command conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost. I was able to successfully install xgboost as on 23-03-2018. 
     https://anaconda.org/anaconda/py-xgboost

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The easiest way (Worked for me) is to do the following:

```
anaconda search -t conda xgboost
```

You will get a list of install-able features like this:

[image]

for example if you want to install the first one on the list **mndrake/xgboost** (FOR WINDOWS-64bits):

```
conda install -c mndrake xgboost
```

If you're in a Unix system you can choose any other package with "**linux-64**" on the right.

- **Update on 22/10/2020:**

Without searching in conda list of channels, you can install it using (source: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/py-xgboost) :

```
conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost
```

Comment: It was useful. Using this method i successfully installed xgboost on Anaconda 4.3 on linux platform.  I had to try through many version listed and finally `conda install -c rdonnelly py-xgboost` worked.

Comment: This 2 commands +
 this instruction [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_XGBoost_For_Anaconda_on_Windows) allow me to use xgBoost on Windows 10.

Comment: This method gives me conflict as mndrake version is for python 2.7 I think. I needed a python 3.5 solution

Comment: @deadcode The first command in this answer shows you how to find the version that works for your version(s) of Python.

Comment: this one gets me package for python 2.7; however I need python 3.6

Comment: @cloudscomputes normaly you get a table with all the columns `Name  |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms | Builds `. Look at Builds you should find py36xxxxxx

Comment: Just tried in Windows and the only message I get: `Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org`. What is it?

Comment: This was great. Note that for me the search command was `conda search <xgboost>` (or whatever package)

Answer (score 80):

Anaconda's website addresses this problem here: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/py-xgboost.

```
conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost
```

This fixed the problem for me with no problems.

Comment: the installation completed succesfully but when running the module i am getting     ########## self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Comment: conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost

Comment: for me `conda install py-xgboost` worked fine (no need for channel)

Comment: `conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost` is the recommendation on the Anaconda website link provided. It worked for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but removing the channel worked. So `conda install py-xgboost`.

Comment: what is the diff between xgboost and py-xgboost

Answer (score 16):

1. Download package from [this website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#xgboost). 
   I downloaded `xgboost-0.6-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` for anaconda 3 (python 3.6)
2. Put the package in directory `C:\`
3. Open anaconda 3 prompt
4. Type `cd C:\`
5. Type `pip install C:\xgboost-0.6-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`
6. Type `conda update scikit-learn`

Comment: A answer for offline installation

Answer (score 13):

After trying some things the only thing that worked for me is:

```
conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost
```

Answer (score 9):

I was able to install xgboost for Python in Windows yesterday [by following this link](https://dnc1994.com/2016/03/installing-xgboost-on-windows/). But when I tried to import using Anaconda, it failed. I recognized this is due to the fact that Anaconda has a different Python distribution. I then searched again and [found this great article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_XGBoost_For_Anaconda_on_Windows?lang=en) which made it!

The trick is after installing successfully for regular Python, to have it work for Anaconda, you just need to pull up the Anaconda prompt and cd into this folder "code\xgboost\python-package", then run:

```
python setup.py install
```

And voila! The article says you need to add the path, but for me it worked directly. Good luck!

Also copied below the original contents in case the link is not available...

> Once the last command completes the build is done.  We can now install
>   the Python module.  What follows depends on the Python distribution
>   you are using.  For Anaconda, I will simply use the Anaconda prompt,
>   and type the following in it (after the prompt, in my case [Anaconda3]
>   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN>):

```
[Anaconda3] C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN>cd code\xgboost\python-package
The point is to move to the python-package directory of XGBoost.  Then type:
[Anaconda3] C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\code\xgboost\python-package>python setup.py install
```

> We are almost done.  Let's launch a notebook to test XGBoost. 
>   Importing it directly causes an error.  In order to avoid it we must
>   add the path to the g++ runtime libraries to the os environment path
>   variable with:

```
import os

mingw_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\\mingw64\\bin'

os.environ['PATH'] = mingw_path + ';' + os.environ['PATH']
```

> We can then import xgboost and run a small example.

```
import xgboost as xgb 
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rand(5,10) # 5 entities, each contains 10 features
label = np.random.randint(2, size=5) # binary target
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix( data, label=label)

dtest = dtrain

param = {'bst:max_depth':2, 'bst:eta':1, 'silent':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic' }
param['nthread'] = 4
param['eval_metric'] = 'auc'

evallist  = [(dtest,'eval'), (dtrain,'train')]

num_round = 10
bst = xgb.train( param, dtrain, num_round, evallist )

bst.dump_model('dump.raw.txt')
```

> We are all set!

Comment: Works perfectly without adding to path. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In my case, I've to add (import os, os.environ['PATH']=...) the path to the g++ runtime libraries to os environment every time before call 'import xgboost', otherwise I get the [same error](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/977). Surely, I've added path to the g++ libraries to os environment manually and after each call it appends PATH by duplicate. It works, but looks like not the best way. Is threre another decision?

Answer (score 7):

I'm able to install using the following commands (in Windows 10) :

```
conda install -c mikesilva xgboost

conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```

Comment: "conda install -c mikesilva xgboost" works on Windows 7 64bit, python 3.6 and Anaconda 1.6.14

Comment: I think it should be made clear that only one of the two is needed.

Answer (score 4):

GUYS ITS NOT THAT EASY:- 
PLEASE FOLLOW BELOW STEP TO GET TO MARK

So here's what I did to finish a 64-bit build on Windows:

Download and install MinGW-64: sourceforge.net /projects/mingw-w64/

On the first screen of the install prompt make sure you set the Architecture to x86_64 and the Threads to win32
I installed to C:\mingw64 (to avoid spaces in the file path) so I added this to my PATH environment variable: C:\ mingw64 \ mingw64 \ bin(Please remove spaces)

I also noticed that the make utility that is included in bin\mingw64 is called mingw32-make so to simplify things I just renamed this to make

Open a Windows command prompt and type gcc. You should see something like "fatal error: no input file"

Next type make. You should see something like "No targets specified and no makefile found"

Type git. If you don't have git, install it and add it to your PATH.
These should be all the tools you need to build the xgboost project. To get the source code run these lines:

- cd c:\
- git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
- cd xgboost
- git submodule init
- git submodule update
- cp make/mingw64.mk config.mk
- make -j4
  Note that I ran this part from a Cygwin shell. If you are using the Windows command prompt you should be able to change cp to copy and arrive at the same result. However, if the build fails on you for any reason I would recommend trying again using cygwin.

If the build finishes successfully, you should have a file called xgboost.exe located in the project root. To install the Python package, do the following:

- cd python-package
- python setup.py install
  Now you should be good to go. Open up Python, and you can import the package with:
- import xgboost as xgb
  To test the installation, I went ahead and ran the basic_walkthrough.py file that was included in the demo/guide-python folder of the project and didn't get any errors.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial!

Everything went fine EXCEPT when I tried the make command, it did a bunch of stuff but failed at the last second at:

g++ error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory
Makefile:140 recipe for target 'lib/libxgboost.dll' failed
mingw32-make: ***[lib/libxgbost.dll] Error 1

Comment: @HeavyBreathing I guess now it is more easier to install ... when i posted this back then it was too difficult

Answer (score 4):

You can download the xgboost package to your local computer, and you better place the xgboost source file under D:\ or C:\ (ps: download address: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#xgboost, and select "**xgboost-0.6-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl**",but it is up to your operation system), and you open the Anaconda prompt, type in `pip install D:\xgboost-0.6-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`, then you can successful install xgboost into your anaconda

Comment: Best way to do it offline or behind a company firewall/VM !

Answer (score 4):

if you found an issue when you try to import xgboost (my case it is Windows 10 and anaconda spyder) do the following:

1. Click on the windows icon (start button!)
2. Select and expand the anaconda folder
3. Run the Anaconda Prompt (as Administrator)
4. Type the following command as it is mentioned in https://anaconda.org/anaconda/py-xgboost

***conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost***

[image]

That's all...Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Try running this on Anaconda prompt

```
pip install xgboost
```

This worked for me on Spyder with Python 3.5

Comment: That will install it from pypi, it's preferable to install it from one of conda repositories via `conda install`

Answer (score 2):

I figured out easy way to install XgBoost by mix of what is mentioned [here](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-on-windows).

Step 1: 
Install gitbash from [here](http://gitforwindows.org/) and start gitbash.

Step 2: `git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost`

Step 3: `git submodule init`

```
       git submodule update
```

step 4: `alias make='mingw32-make'`

step 5: `cp make/mingw64.mk config.mk; make -j4`

step 6: Goto Anaconda prompt and if you have a conda environment then activate that environment like my was py35 so I activate it by typing activate py35

```
cd python-package
python setup.py install
```

step 7: setup the Path in system environment variable to the path where you installed xgboost/python-package.

Comment: I followed your steps but i wasn't able to pass step 5 until i set the environment variables for gcc.exe.
Just adding this here to help someone else

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your conda prompt:

```
python -m pip install xgboost
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
conda install libxgboost
```

Answer (score 0):

The package directory states that xgboost is unstable for windows and is disabled:

> pip installation on windows is currently disabled for further invesigation, please install from github.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xgboost/

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda3 version 4.4.0[check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hQDN.jpg)
Go to Anaconda -> Environments -> from the dropdown select not installed -> If you can see xgboost pr Py-xgboost select and click apply.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of dependencies of anaconda that have changed over the past years and won't work if you used them now. Some of the answers need serious updation.

I found this command did the job for me :

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```

You may also want to look at the official documentation of anaconda for xgboost:

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/xgboost

Comment: PackagesNotFoundError:

Comment: No. I got that error. Installing py-xgboost though the console GUI worked though.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this command and it worked for me.

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install xgboost
```

Answer (score 0):

Open anaconda prompt and run

```
pip install xgboost
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install it using `pip`:

```
pip3 install --default-timeout=100 xgboost
```

Answer (score -1):

This simple helped me you don't have to include anything at the end because if you include something, some of your packages will be upgraded but some will be downgraded.
You can get this from this url: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/py-xgboost

```
conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost
```

Answer (score -3):

1. Look  here [https://github.com/Rafi993/xgboost/](https://github.com/Rafi993/xgboost/commit/38abcf1c47346500382714624fafb81b62979aa4) for building xgboost on your machine. There are many different varieties of the solution above, but it seems that the version in the link above is the good one. At least that worked for me: I've tested it on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008.
2. Then run the following commands in cmd in order to install python bindings:
   `cd python-package
   python setup.py install`
3. You might also need a proper mingw (google for tdm-gcc)
   and the latest setuptools from anaconda.

I hope it will help