# Python XGboost import DeprecationWarning

Tags: python, import, conda, xgboost

When running the code line:

```
import xgboost
```

I get the following warning:

```
 DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
```

"This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)

I have installed xgboost using:

```
conda install py-xgboost
```

I use pycharm. What should I do in order to run xgboost?

**EDIT:
here is the full errror code:**

```
C:\Users\username\Miniconda3\python.exe "C:/Users/username/Documents/Tools/BigData/Kaggle ML Course/main2.py"
C:\Users\username\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py:41: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/username/Documents/Tools/BigData/Kaggle ML Course/main2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import xgboost
  File "C:\Users\username\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .core import DMatrix, Booster
  File "C:\Users\username\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 112, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()
  File "C:\Users\username\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 106, in _load_lib
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
  File "C:\Users\username\Miniconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\username\Miniconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: I think it's just warning. You're ok to use it. Warning is nothing but they gonna remove the module in 0.20 version but for now you can use it.

Comment: After the warning I can't do anything, the program just stops

Comment: You could always update the package using "conda update"

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139108/how-to-install-xgboost-in-anaconda-python-windows-platform

Comment: I installed it today, so it's updated for sure. I have miniconda, so I need anaconda?

Answer (score -1):

conda update should be the intended operation in such situations and to suppress the warnings.. let me know if it worked.