# How to install SHAP (Shapley) for Python

Tags: python, installation, xgboost

Tried to install Shapley package (available in R)  using

```
install shap
```

but got an error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: shap, iml
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for shap ... error
Complete output from command C:\Users\Toly_Novik\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c     "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\TOLY_N~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp  \\pip-install-o0p96nl3\\shap\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\TOLY_N~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-538qnmm2 --python-tag cp36:
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\shap
copying shap\datasets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\shap
copying shap\plots.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\shap
copying shap\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\shap
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\shap\explainers
copying shap\explainers\ime.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\shap\explainers
copying shap\explainers\kernel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\shap\explainers
copying shap\explainers\mimic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\shap\explainers
copying shap\explainers\pytree.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\shap\explainers
copying shap\explainers\tree.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\shap\explainers
copying shap\explainers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6 \shap\explainers
running build_ext
numpy.get_include() C:\Users\Toly_Novik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include
building 'shap._cext' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual  C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

Same story for
    install xgboost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you meant to install shapely (https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/)?
In python you can install shapely by doing `pip install shapely`

For windows shapley can be installed by downloading .whl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely and do

`pip install <name of whl file>`

or if you are using anaconda you can use conda-forge to get shapely

`conda config --add channels conda-forge
 conda install shapely`

---

To install xgboost see http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_intro.html
For this you might need gcc (c/c++ compiler) or equivalent Microsoft alternative.

For xgboost with conda you can see this stackoverflow.com/questions/35139108/… or simply do `conda install py-xgboost`

Comment: got error    File "C:\Users\TOLY_N~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qm2tsp1b\shapely\shapely\_buildcfg.py", line 200, in <module>
        lgeos = CDLL("geos_c.dll")
      File "C:\Users\Toly_Novik\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Comment: I guess you are using windows. See note for windows
`Installing Shapely 1.6
Windows users have two good installation options: the wheels at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely and the Anaconda platform’s [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.github.io/) channel.`

Comment: You can download the .whl file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely and do `pip install <wheel-file-name>`

Comment: Ok sorry, I see from your error message that you are using anaconda. So you can also do `conda config --add channels conda-forge ` and `conda install shapely`

Comment: For xgboost with conda you can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139108/how-to-install-xgboost-in-anaconda-python-windows-platform

or simply do `conda install xgboost` ;)

Comment: @umang_gupta - This is what I got when tried to install xgboost:                                   
Solving environment: failed
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - xgboost

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda-fusion/win-64    I had to delete some channels due to comment length limitations

Comment: Thanks for informing, I have updated the answer you pointed on other post.

Comment: kindly do not follow this answer. this is for a geo package called shapely. for issues installing shap due to visual studio not available you would need to install the same

Comment: SHAP is short for SHapley Additive exPlanations.

Answer (score 7):

Are you trying to install shap - a library for explaining Machine Learning models?  If so use

```
pip install shap
```

See the shap documentation for more info: https://pypi.org/project/shap/

Comment: right answer, shapely is some geo package, shap is for machine learning.  I installed it on windows using conda.

Comment: I tried installing shap with pip as well as conda but later on , while importing shap i get a bunch of errors. Specifically a type error: an integer is required (got type bytes)  Any suggestions please?

Comment: Check out the answers on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58700384/how-to-fix-typeerror-an-integer-is-required-got-type-bytes-error-when-tryin

Comment: conda install -c conda-forge shap

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/slundberg/shap.git
```

Using the `pip install` only, did not work for me (errors running tests), neither did the conda approach.