# Spark Installation Problems -TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes) - spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7, hadoop 2.7.1, python 3.8.2

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to install Spark on my 64 -bit Windows OS computer. I installed python 3.8.2. I have pip with version 20.0.2. I download spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7 and set environment variables as HADOOP_HOME, SPARK_HOME and I add pyspark to path variable. When I run pyspark from cmd I see the error given below:

```
C:\Users\aa>pyspark
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aa\Downloads\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkConf
  File "C:\Users\aa\Downloads\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
  File "C:\Users\aa\Downloads\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pyspark import accumulators
  File "C:\Users\aa\Downloads\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\accumulators.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pyspark.serializers import read_int, PickleSerializer
  File "C:\Users\aa\Downloads\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\serializers.py", line 72, in <module>
    from pyspark import cloudpickle
  File "C:\Users\aa\Downloads\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 145, in <module>
    _cell_set_template_code = _make_cell_set_template_code()
  File "C:\Users\aa\Downloads\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 126, in _make_cell_set_template_code
    return types.CodeType(
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

I want to import pyspark to my python code but in Pycharm but after I run my code file I take an error like **TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)** also.  I uninstall python 3.8.2 and tried with python 2.7 but in this case I take an depreciation error. I take the error given below and update pip installer.

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyspark (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyspark
```

Then I run `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` to update pip but I have `TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)`  problem again.

```
C:\Users\aa>python --version
Python 3.8.2

C:\Users\aa>pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from c:\users\aa\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

C:\Users\aa>java --version
java 14 2020-03-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14+36-1461)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14+36-1461, mixed mode, sharing)
```

How can I fix and overcome the problem? Currently I have spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7 and python 3.8.2. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58700384/how-to-fix-typeerror-an-integer-is-required-got-type-bytes-error-when-tryin

Comment: Thank you @D Untouchable. I apply the steps. I install python 3.7.6(downversion), latest version of pip, java 8, spark-hadoop 2.4.4 (downversion), hadoop 2.7 (for winutils.exe) then everything is allright now. But I did not handle and use with python 3.8. I will search it thanks again!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)' error when trying to run pyspark after installing spark 2.4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58700384/how-to-fix-typeerror-an-integer-is-required-got-type-bytes-error-when-tryin)

Comment: Thanks for your help @ei-grad ! I applied the steps in that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58700384/how-to-fix-typeerror-an-integer-is-required-got-type-bytes-error-when-tryin) but it did not work with python 3.8, I have version incompatiblity problems and took some errors again then I downgraded pthon version and problem is solved!

Answer (score 15):

It is a python3.8 and spark version compatibility problem you can see : https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/26194.

To make it functional (to a certain extent) you need to :

- Replace the **cloudpickle.py** file in your pyspark directory by its 1.1.1 version, find it in : https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle/blob/v1.1.1/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py.
- Edit the **cloudpickle.py** file to add :

```
def print_exec(stream):
    ei = sys.exc_info()
    traceback.print_exception(ei[0], ei[1], ei[2], None, stream)
```

you'll then be able to import pyspark.

Comment: Thank you @Amine SAIBI ! I will research it !

Comment: Thank youuuuuuu!!!!