# PySpark 2.4.5 is not compatible with Python 3.8.3, how do I solve this?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

**Code**

```
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf

conf=SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('Test App')
sc=SparkContext(conf)
```

**Error Message**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Test\PycharmProjects\python-test\MainFile.py", line 5, in <module>
        from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
      File "C:\Test\Python_3.8.3_Latest\lib\site-packages\pyspark\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
        from pyspark.context import SparkContext
      File "C:\Test\Python_3.8.3_Latest\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 31, in <module>
        from pyspark import accumulators
      File "C:\Test\Python_3.8.3_Latest\lib\site-packages\pyspark\accumulators.py", line 97, in <module>
        from pyspark.serializers import read_int, PickleSerializer
      File "C:\Test\Python_3.8.3_Latest\lib\sit`enter code here`e-packages\pyspark\serializers.py", line 72, in <module>
        from pyspark import cloudpickle
      File "C:\Test\Python_3.8.3_Latest\lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 145, in <module>
        _cell_set_template_code = _make_cell_set_template_code()
      File "C:\Test\Python_3.8.3_Latest\lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 126, in _make_cell_set_template_code
        return types.CodeType(
    TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)' error when trying to run pyspark after installing spark 2.4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58700384/how-to-fix-typeerror-an-integer-is-required-got-type-bytes-error-when-tryin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although latest Spark doc says that it has support for `Python 2.7+/3.4+`, it actually doesn't support Python 3.8 yet. According to [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/26194) PR, Python 3.8 support is expected in Spark 3.0. So, either you can try out Spark 3.0 preview release (assuming you're not gonna do a production deployment) or 'temporarily' fall back to Python 3.6/3.7 for Spark 2.4.x.

Comment: I downgraded to Python 3.7.7

Comment: Is this problem of compatibility with Python 3.8 solved with pyspark 3.1.1 ?

Comment: @dallonsi [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29536) says the issue is fixed in spark v3.0.0, so it should work.

Answer (score -2):

Spark 3.0 has been released for a while now and is compatible with Python 3.8.+.
The error you experienced is no longer reproducible.