# Stuck installing PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter

I've followed along and been trying to install PySpark on my MacBook, but when I finished installing I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vasquezk26/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/vasquezk26/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_core/command.py", line 247, in main
    command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)
  File "/Users/vasquezk26/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_core/command.py", line 133, in _jupyter_abspath
    raise Exception(
```

I have PySpark installed, findspark, as well as anaconda3.

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: How are you trying to install PySpark? By using `pip install pyspark` I was able to install it easily in linux machines.

Comment: I was using pip install.

Comment: it looks like you truncated the error message on the most interesting part... would you please be able to add the following lines in the exception message you received? and please add details of the versions you are using (Python version [I assume 3.8 but write it explicitly please], Spark version...)

Comment: fwiw, you should run pip commands outside of jupyter

Answer (score 0):

As reported in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62208730/pyspark-2-4-5-is-not-compatible-with-python-3-8-3-how-do-i-solve-this) PySpark doesn't support Python 3.8 (unless you are using Spark 3.0 which looks like to be solving this problem).

I'm not sure if the error message you are having is because of that but I had problem installing it too on Ubuntu 20.04 which has Python 3.8 as default.

My suggestion is the same as the one reported in that answer: try to use a previous version of Python (3.6 should do) or, at this point, try to use Spark version 3.0 which looks compatible with Python 3.8.