# Solve TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes) in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Hi I'm new on Apache Spark. I installed Spark 2.4.7 on an Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, I'm using python 3.7 with Anaconda3 (Anaconda3-2020-02-Linux-x86_64.sh) and openjdk 14.0.2. I try to read from a Kafka topic with this python script:

```
from pyspark import RDD
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import json
import logging

#define top level module logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

#Spark context details
sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSparkStreamingKafka")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc,2)
#Creating Kafka direct stream
dks = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ["temperature"], {"metadata.broker.list":"ip_address:9092"})
counts = dks.pprint()
logger.info(dks)

#Starting Spark context
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

and I try to launch from command row with:

```
/home/kafka/Documenti/spark2/bin/spark-submit ~/Documenti/spark2/examples/testkafkaspark/testkafka.py 
localhost 9999
```

but I receive this error:

```
    (testkafkaspark) kafka@kafka:~/Documenti/spark2/examples/testkafkaspark$ /home/kafka/Documenti/spark2/bin/spark-submit ~/Documenti/spark2/examples/testkafkaspark/testkafka.py localhost 9999
21/04/21 15:53:12 WARN Utils: Your hostname, kafka resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using my_ip instead (on interface ens160)
21/04/21 15:53:12 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/home/kafka/Documenti/spark2/jars/spark-unsafe_2.11-2.4.7.jar) to method java.nio.Bits.unaligned()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
21/04/21 15:53:13 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kafka/Documenti/spark2/examples/testkafkaspark/testkafka.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pyspark
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/home/kafka/Documenti/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/home/kafka/Documenti/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/home/kafka/Documenti/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 97, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/home/kafka/Documenti/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 72, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/home/kafka/Documenti/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 145, in <module>
  File "/home/kafka/Documenti/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 126, in _make_cell_set_template_code
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
21/04/21 15:53:13 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
21/04/21 15:53:13 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-c5b12b40-a19b-4ac1-88a8-6d1ddb8b9679
```

I read some topic ([How to fix 'TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)' error when trying to run pyspark after installing spark 2.4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58700384/how-to-fix-typeerror-an-integer-is-required-got-type-bytes-error-when-tryin)) about this problem but any of these solve my problem.
I use Pycharm with a conda environement with python 3.7. Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Use Java 8 for Spark 2. Java 14 is not supported.

Comment: I'm usin open jdk..it is different from java 8 (I suppose it is java Oracle).

Comment: I mean openjdk 8

Comment: I downgraded to open-jdk1.8 but it can't solve.

Comment: did you change the java path?

Comment: also 2020-02 anaconda is probably python 3.8, not 3.7