# Unable to install xgboost on conda-forge

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, xgboost, conda-forge

I tried to install xgboost on my Anaconda package on Windows 10. I'm using python 3.7.
I ran the following command;

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```

I failed to do so. The error is shown below;

[image]

If I try `conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost`, xgboost can be installed but I prefer the xgboost package from conda-forge because it's more updated.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and post that. Or, maybe not, since you don't seem to be programming that software at all, so you don't have a programming question. Instead, check the bug tracker and file a bug there if you don't find the issue recorded there.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install xgboost in Anaconda Python (Windows platform)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139108/how-to-install-xgboost-in-anaconda-python-windows-platform)

Comment: I am having the exact same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately as of today, conda-forge does not yet offer a windows build for xgboost. See also the related github issue [issue#3](https://github.com/conda-forge/xgboost-feedstock/issues/3).

Comment: If that's the case, then windows 10 users will have to use the py-xgboost from anaconda which is an outdated version. Anaconda packages are inferior to conda-forge packages because they tend to be outdated in comparison.